# What is a good metric to evaluate ranking without retrieval?

Tags: machine-learning, model-evaluation, ranking, metric

The problem is predicting the ranking of a list using some features e.g.
`rank_metric([A, B, C, D, E], [A, B, C, D, E])` should be 1
`rank_metric([A, B, C, D, E], [B, A, C, D, E])` should be lower
`rank_metric([A, B, C, D, E], [E, A, B, C, D])` should be even lower
I came across Kendall's τ while looking for a good metric to use. Is this a recommended metric for this case and are there others that are more suitable?

Also if I wanna measure the performance based on only the first predicted item what would be a good measure then? a simple solution would be to just have something like
`1 - actual_index_of_predicted/len(list)`

Comment: Check out [Rank Correlation - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_correlation#:~:text=In%20statistics%2C%20a%20rank%20correlation,third%22%2C%20etc.%20to%20different)

Comment: Thanks i also landed on this page during my search but thought maybe I could get more insight into a suitable metric for the described case by asking

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to check the normalized version of Damerau–Levenshtein distance. It is technically a string metric for measuring the edit distance between two sequences. However, in this case, it can be used as a ranking metric. A python package called pyxDamerauLevenshtein implements this distance metric.

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the probability that a randomly chosen pair of elements from your list is ranked correctly. This generalizes [ROC AUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic#Area_under_the_curve), which is equivalent to the probability that a randomly chosen positive instance is ranked higher than a randomly chosen negative instance for binary classification. The advantage of this metric is swapping any two successively ranked elements changes performance by a fixed amount. So in your example,

`rank_metric([A, B, C, D, E], [A, B, C, D, E])` is 1

`rank_metric([A, B, C, D, E], [B, A, C, D, E])` is $1 - \frac{1}{10}$

`rank_metric([A, B, C, D, E], [B, C, A, D, E])` is $1 - \frac{2}{10}$

`rank_metric([A, B, C, D, E], [B, C, A, D, E])` is $1 - \frac{2}{10}$

`rank_metric([A, B, C, D, E], [E, D, C, B, A])` is $1 - \frac{10}{10}=0$

You can find an N log N implementation of this metric [here](https://finraos.github.io/model-validation-toolkit/docs/html/metrics.html#mvtk.metrics.rank_auc).